# Equivilence of an interface with an iterator method from Java to C# which will then be implemented on a class?

Tags: java, c#, interface

I'm converting a project from Java to C#. In this Java project, there is an interface: public interface TrackIterator, then it as a member in it: public Iterator createIterator();. The class that is going to implement it has createIterator as a method which returns an Arraylist of objects (in C# List),How would I convert this from Java to C# so I can implement it on a converted C# class

```
// interface
public interface TrackIterator
{
    public Iterator createIterator();
}

// class that implements it
public class trackList implements TrackIterator
{
    // other methods, fields, etc

    // method from interface TrackIterator
    public Iterator createIterator()
    {
        // popularSongs is an ArrayList of objects in Java, in C# it's a List<MyTrack>
        return popularSongs.iterator();
    } 
}
```

Comment: `public interface TrackList : IEnumerable` see [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To answer this question we should know how this class/interface is going to be used.... do you want to be able to change the content of the array or do you really only need an _iterator_. What type are those songs of? etc...there are different approaches depending on how this property is going to be called.

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to implement `IEnumerable<TrackList>` if you want to create a custom iterator over the `TrackList` type.

Comment: You wouldn't implement your own iterator, you would simply do `new List<Track>` or `Enumerable.Empty<Track>()`

Comment: I'd sack the `TrackIterator` and just implement `IEnumerable<MyTrack>` directly on `trackList` (btw, conventions in c# are that classes should be UpperCamelCase, so it should be `TrackList`)

Comment: This is what I'm converting. The createIterator method is basically just going to return the list. Then I'm supposed to initialize the object that implements what is going to be an IEnumerable, then I'm going to need to initialize an IEnumerable? To pass the collection to so I can later WriteLine them to the console? I'm confused in that portion too, but don't know if I would get in trouble for putting too many questions in one post. Will probably end up asking 1 or 2 new questions based on the next steps.  http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/10/iterator-design-pattern-tutorial/

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a custom iterator at all, all you need is a `List<Track>` which you can later iterate with `foreach`.

Comment: Why did you use a non-generic Iterator in the first place?  Why not just use Iterator<Track> in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you can go about this in two ways. The first would be to make `TrackList` implement `IEnumerable<Track>`, and roll your own enumerable:

```
public class Track 
{ 
    public bool IsGoodTrack => true;
}

public class TrackList : IEnumerable<Track>
{
    private List<Track> tracks = new List<Track>();
    public IEnumerator<Track> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Implement custom logic here.
        foreach (var track in tracks)
        {
            if (track.IsGoodTrack())
              yield return track;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Or, if there's no kind of special logic over exposing a `List<Track>`, simply use a `List<Track>` wherever you need one:

```
public class Foo
{
  // Foo has a `List<Track>` property:
  public List<Track> Tracks { get; } = new List<Track>();
}
```

In case you just want to get a list with tracks and print them to the console, it is as simple as:

```
var listOfTracks = new List<Track>();
foreach (var track in listOfTracks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(track);
}
```